# Import HTML sections with supporting other javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my HTML file, I imported some HTML sections eg: `Header`, `Footer` using Jquery.

```
$(function(){
              $("#leftsidebar").load("leftsidebar");
              $("#topnav").load("topnav");
              $("#footer").load("footer");
          });
```

The issue is, those HTML sections have a dropdown functionality which supported by another js file.

```
<script src="js/custom.min.js"></script>
```

This functionaly doesn't work in this way. It works only if I add above js file to that html section. I need to remain this import in the main html file becuase this js file has usages in other html sections as well.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Would you mind providing the shared function in question within your custom.min.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('selector').load(htmlUrl,function(){
  $.getScript(scriptUrl);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript is applied before your new elements are loaded and so you don 't see the effects. So, you need to get your javascript file again by calling `$.getScript()` like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#leftsidebar").load("leftsidebar");
    $("#topnav").load("topnav");
    $("#footer").load("footer",function(){
        $.getScript("js/custom.min.js");
    });
});
```